# Sorting a Python dictionary by value - what is wrong here?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Consider this Python code:

```
with open('data.json', 'rb') as fp:
data = json.load(fp,encoding="utf-8")

list_of_years = []

for datas in data:
list_of_years.append(data[datas]['year'])

print set(list_of_years)

received_letters = {}

sent_letters = {}

for years in set(list_of_years):
print years
number_of_sent_letters =0
number_of_received_letters =0
for datas in data:
    if (data[datas]['year'] == years):
        if ' Luther, Martin' in data [datas] ['sender']:
            number_of_sent_letters+=1
print "The number of sent letters:" +str(number_of_sent_letters)
sent_letters[years]=number_of_sent_letters

for datas in data:
    if (data[datas]['year'] == years):
        if ' Luther, Martin' in data [datas] ['receiver']:
            number_of_received_letters+=1
print "The number of received letters:" +str(number_of_received_letters)
received_letters[years]=number_of_received_letters

sent_letters[years] = {number_of_sent_letters}
sorted_sent_letters[years] = sorted(sent_letters[years].iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

received_letters[years] = {number_of_received_letters}
sorted_received_letters[years] = sorted(received_letters[years].iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

I tried to sort the two dictionaries `received_letters` and `sent_letters` as suggested in an answer for another question concerning sorting dictionaries by value, but it does not work in my case... All I get as a result is the error message

> set object has no attribute iteritems

for the concerning the fourth from the last line.

What is wrong here?

Comment: On the face of it your indentation is wrong. For instance, the second line `data = json.load(fp,encoding="utf-8")` should begin with whitespace so your program won't compile. If you have a correctly-indented version that runs then please post it, as we can't tell what you mean much better than the compiler can!

Comment: I am also sure that `data[datas]['year']` should be `datas['year']`, which is possibly the source of your problem. What output do you get from `print set(list_of_years)`?

Comment: Please fix your code indentation and provide the full trace back of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you say you are trying to sort dictionaries, but your code only tries to sort a set containing one single item!

```
sent_letters[years] = {number_of_sent_letters}
sorted_sent_letters[years] = sorted(sent_letters[years].iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

As `number_of_sent_letters` is an integer, `sent_letters[years]` is just a singleton set.

I suppose you want to do:

```
sorted_sent_letters = sorted(sent_letters.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

And you should do it outside of the loop...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that what you want is this, but I'm not clear what sort you want to do as all you've generated at the end is two dictionaries where each year is related to its number of letters.

```
with open('dataset.json', 'rb') as fp:
    dataset = json.load(fp, encoding="utf-8")

set_of_years = {}

for data in dataset:
    set_of_years.append(data['year'])

print set_of_years

sent_letters, received_letters = {}, {}

for year in set_of_years:

    print year

    for data in dataset:
        if (data['year'] == year):
            if 'Luther, Martin' in data['sender']:
                sent_letters[year]     += 1
            if 'Luther, Martin' in data['receiver']:
                received_letters[year] += 1

    print "The number of sent letters: %d" % sent_letters[year]
    print "The number of received letters: %d" % received_letters[year]
```

After that it depends on what you want. You have coded what looks like a sort that turns `sent_letters` (and `received_letters`) into a list of (date, count) tuples and sorts them by the second value -- the count. Written properly that would be

```
itemgetter_1 = operator.itemgetter(1)
sorted_sent_letters     = sorted(sent_letters.items(),     key=itemgetter_1)
sorted_received_letters = sorted(received_letters.items(), key=itemgetter_1)
```

or, using lambdas

```
count_key = lambda pair: pair[1]
sorted_sent_letters     = sorted(sent_letters.items(),     key=count_key)
sorted_received_letters = sorted(received_letters.items(), key=count_key)
```

But it seems more likely that you want just a list of years sorted by the letter count, so you would need

```
count_key = lambda year: data[year]
sorted_sent_letters     = sorted(sent_letters,     key=count_key)
sorted_received_letters = sorted(received_letters, key=count_key)
```

I hope that helps